# Using objects for lookups, I cant see my mistake

Tags: javascript, algorithm, object, lookup

```
// Setup
function phoneticLookup(val) {
    let result = "";
  
    // Only change code below this line
  
    const lookup = {
      "":undefined,
      "alpha": "Adams",
      "bravo":"Boston",
      "charlie":"Chicago",
      "delta":"Denver",
      "echo":"Easy",
      "foxtrot":"Frank",
    }
    const value = lookup[val]
    result += value;
    // Only change code above this line
    return result;
  }
  console.log(  phoneticLookup(""))
```

The code results as I expected, the app works of this way, if you pass a value == to an String of the object, the app shall return the key of the property, but the console sends me an error message, but the output is undefined if I put a "", so I suppose that everything it's okey, what could be wrong?

```
// running tests
phoneticLookup("") should equal undefined
// tests completed
// console output
undefined
```

Comment: Looks OK to me, note that `undefined` is your requested output and not an error message.  Are you getting some other error?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. What **exactly** is going wrong? Looking up a property name in your object will result in `undefined` when the property is not in the object.

Comment: `undefined` is an actual thing in JavaScript, but `""+undefined` results in the string "undefined". The visuals may vary a little between environments, you can simply check via running `console.log(undefined,""+undefined)`. It may be worth mentioning that `console.log()` actually returns `undefined`, which the console may display afterwards (like if you run this code snippet via copy-pasting it into the prompt).

Comment: Iam actually using quokka and it returns undefined, not and string so I dont understand what is happening, the output should be undefined if a pass value == "", is maybe something about the freeCodeCamp console? And by the way, that's the only error that I am getting

Comment: As stated by people above, because `"undefined" !== undefined`

Comment: but the console gives me and undefined, not "undefined", I tried with typeof and returns and undefined, not an string

Comment: Well their console is not showing the quotes.

Comment: I am using Vs Code with quokka and typeof, I mean, you know typeof returns the type

Comment: Change your code to `const result = lookup[val]; return result;`

Comment: That works man, thank you, but what was wrong with my code? Other guys couldn't see any mistake neither

Comment: @Arrow3847, the problem that is happening is because there are two **versions** of the word **undefined** that can be returned. One is an actual string, and the other is a primitive value. Depending on what you are doing with it to display, you might not see a big difference. But as mentioned above the string version "undefined" is not the same as the undefined primitive value. When you added "" to whatever was being returned, you were converting the primitive value to a string and they are different. I'm calling it a word and versions because I couldn't think of a different way to describe it

Comment: Why would you do `+=` when there is nothing to concatenate? When the right hand side is `undefined` then this `+=` will convert that `undefined` to the string `"undefined"`, which you don't want. But even if the right hand side is a string, there is still no reason to do `+=`. This exercise does not require to concatenate anything. NB: you don't need that `"": undefined` in your lookup object.

Comment: Okey thank you for your explanation, and that's because the =+ operator right? Is converting the undefined value of "" to an string because I am adding it to the result ="", sorry for so many question, I am a beginner.

Comment: A trick would be to use `console.log([value])` (note the square brackets) instead of `console.log(value)`.